# QTextBrowser hyperlink click loses uppercase

Tags: qt, url

I'm using Qt 4.6.3

When text browser html has a reference

```
<a href="myprotocol://ABC"/>click me!</a>
```

then on click, it emits the anchorClicked signal with url

```
myprotocol://abc
```

How can it be fixed (I need the correct case...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**QUrl always lowercases host names.**

> QUrl conforms to the URI specification from RFC 3986 (Uniform Resource Identifier: Generic Syntax), and includes scheme extensions from RFC 1738 (Uniform Resource Locators). Case folding rules in QUrl conform to RFC 3491 (Nameprep: A Stringprep Profile for Internationalized Domain Names (IDN)).
>
> ...
>
> Note that the case folding rules in Nameprep, which QUrl conforms to, require host names to always be converted to lower case, regardless of the Qt::FormattingOptions used.

([From Qt 4.7 documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qurl.html), closest I can find to 4.6.3)

If you're using "fake" URLs to just pass some data around your application, you can preserve case by using a dummy hostname and passing your real info as the path or a query. E.g. `myprotocol:///ABC` (same as writing localhost/ABC).

Answer (score 2):

In this case the `ABC` interpeted as a host (domain) name of your URL. Although, format does not limit it, and host names are case-insensitive, it is recommended, that URL should be case-sensitive. For example, the W3 [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html):

> URLs in general are case-sensitive (with the exception of machine
>   names). There may be URLs, or parts of URLs, where case doesn't
>   matter, but identifying these may not be easy. Users should always
>   consider that URLs are case-sensitive.

I think, browsers are also follow that rule: all URLs with upper case characters converted into lowercase. I tried this on Chrome, FF and IE.